# asp-append-version="true" not appending version to javascript file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

asp-append-version="true" this should append version to script. With .net core 1.1 it worked just fine. Recently upgraded to version 2.0 and it no longer works. Any ideas why?

Comment: In case absolute path is used, e.g. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js, the hash would not be added. [How does javascript version (asp-append-version) work in ASP.NET Core MVC](//stackoverflow.com/a/42527477)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/issues/471

Basically you now need

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

And to make it easier, you can have a global _ViewImports.cshtml file under the Views folder, and just throw that line in there and it will apply the line to all View pages.

Comment: did this work for you? I tried but its still not appending version to scripts & css files.

Comment: @Priya Which .Net Core version are you using? Did you see Michael Freidgeim comment above, does that apply to you?

Comment: I have Areas in my solution. May be that was the reason. I then added one more _ViewImports.cshtml  inside Areas folder. And its working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, we can do versioning by maintaining config value then used public class to append the version in JS and CSS reference.

CS:

```
  public static class StaticFileHelper
  {
    static string staticVersion;
    static StaticFileHelper()
    {
     staticVersion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JSVersioning"];
    }

    public static string StaticFile(this UrlHelper html, string filename)
    {
        var virtualPath =  ReleaseVirtualPath(filename);
        var root = html.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath;
        if (root.Length > 1) 
        {
            virtualPath = root + virtualPath;
        }
        return virtualPath;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -4):

In case of this I made this solution

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\css\custom.css?v=@Generator.RandomStringGenerator(9)">`

So my random generator is generating different strings for version then I never face with this situation again. Also I am sharing random string generator for interested people.

```
    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static string RandomStringGenerator(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: This will never cache the resource on clients as each page view gets a new random string attached.